# Wolfram Alpha: How to find inflections points of functions involving arbitrary real constants

Tags: calculus, wolfram-alpha

One of the WA demos shows how to find the inflection points of the following function: $x+\sin(x)$.

How would you ask WA to find the inflection points of functions like $x+\sin(ax)$ or $a+bx+\sin(cx)$, where $a,b,c$ are arbitrary real constants?

Answer (score 1):

I would ask for the second derivative, which is $-c^2\sin(cx)$ and then look at the points where it changes sign, i.e. $x_k=k\pi/c$ with $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Yes, but for complicated functions, which is why I would use WA in the first place, this suggestion it not very useful.

Comment: Why it isn't useful? That's how you find inflection points. You compute the second derivative, you find where it vanishes, you check that it changes sign around those points.

Comment: OK. Here is a more interesting example of what I mean. Suppose that $f(x)=1-((x/a)(1+2(x/a))/(\exp(2x/a)-(1+(x/a)))$. How do I find the inflection points using WA without having to myself look for points where the second derivative (which is a complicated function) vanishes?

Comment: You notice that $f_a(x)=f_1(x/a)$, so you completely throw away the parameter. You just study the function with $a=1$ and then the inflection points are just multiplied by $a$.

Comment: The question has not really been answered. Suppose $f(x)=1-(x(1+2x)/(\exp(2x/a)-(1+(x/a))))$. Can WA do it on its own? How?

Comment: Why would I care if WA is capable of doing it? This place is a forum of mathematics, not the user guide to WA

Comment: This was a WA-specific question, not a general mathematics question. But thanks for your input.

Comment: Would something like this be useful? https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5BD%5B1%2Bx%2BSin%5Ba+x%5D,+%7Bx,+2%7D%5D+%3D%3D+0,+x%5D

Comment: I think it could be. I tried your suggestion with the more complicated function $f_a(x)=f(x/a)$ above but I got the "standard computation time exceeded" message. But, I think in general, your suggestion would be a good way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: That's because solving the equation involves trascendental functions and there isn't a nice closed form solution in general. You cannot expect WA to solve any kind of equations

Comment: I understand. I thought that maybe WA could solve transcendental equations involving arbitrary constants. But, I guess it can't. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Well, it can't even solve something like $x+e^x=\sin x$, without parameters. In general, it isn't able to find solutions to arbitrary equations that you throw at it.